# Sort Array but values of nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array I am passing into a chart. However the order of the array matters so that the charts will plots the values left to right.

Here is the array in question:

```
0: ["time", "amount"]
1: [2130, 1100]
2: [2129, 1000]
3: [2136, 2000]
```

The index of 0 for the nested array is time represented in 24 hour time as a number. I need the array to be ordered chronologically based on the values in the sub-arrays index 0.

How can I go about doing this in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Array `sort()` method to order the array by the first element in each sub-array.

```js
const arr = [
  [2130, 1100],
  [2129, 1000],
  [2136, 2000]
];

const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take account of the fact that your first array element contains text values, you can effectively chop that off and then sort what remains and add it back. You sort based on the `0` element of the subarrays:

```js
let data = [
  ["time", "amount"],
  [2130, 1100],
  [2129, 1000],
  [2136, 2000]
];

data = [data[0]].concat(data.slice(1).sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]));
console.log(data);
```